# Link function of Directive is not being called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, c3.js

I have a scenario where I need to show a pie-chart in a popup modal (used ui-bootstrap modal). I used `c3.js` for my pie-chart requirement (inside a directive).

The pie-chart is not loading inside the pop up. But to my surprise when I tried to debug the issue when I opened the console it is loading. When I re-size the window it is loading.

How can i fix this issue?

```
'use strict';
angular.module('App')
    .directive('pieChartDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                chartdata: '=',
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var chart = c3.generate({
                    bindto: '#chart',
                    data: {
                        columns: [
                            ['Javascript', scope.chartdata.Javascript],
                            ['HTML', scope.chartdata.HTML],
                            ['Css', scope.chartdata.Css],
                            ['Angular', scope.chartdata.Angular],
                            ['Bootstrap', scope.chartdata.Bootstrap],
                            ['Jquery', scope.chartdata.Jquery],
                            ['Communication', scope.chartdata.Communication]
                        ],
                        type: 'pie',
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        format: {
                            value: function(value, ratio, id, index) {
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Html:

```
      <div pie-chart-directive chartdata="oChartData">
        <div id="chart"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: `return fnLink` will return the function but won't execute it. Do `compile: fnLink` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by giving size property:

```
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart',
                size: {
                    width:400,
                    height:350
                },
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        ['Javascript', scope.chartdata.Javascript],
                        ['HTML', scope.chartdata.HTML],
                        ['Css', scope.chartdata.Css],
                        ['Angular', scope.chartdata.Angular],
                        ['Bootstrap', scope.chartdata.Bootstrap],
                        ['Jquery', scope.chartdata.Jquery],
                        ['Communication', scope.chartdata.Communication]
                    ],
                    type: 'pie',
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    format: {
                        value: function(value, ratio, id, index) {
                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                }
              });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure, that you include your directive properly in your html code as

> `<div pie-chart-directive></div>`

Maybe you have to change your restriction to 'E' to use your directive as a tag elment

> `<pie-chart-directive chartdata="myData"></pie-chart-directive>`

The reason could be, that at the moment you try to generate the chart, your `'#chart'` div isn't yet present in the dom tree. Therefore you have to resize to trigger a new draw. Try to wait until the dom is loaded

```
$('#chart').ready(function() {
       var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart',
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        ['Javascript', scope.chartdata.Javascript],
                        ['HTML', scope.chartdata.HTML],
                        ['Css', scope.chartdata.Css],
                        ['Angular', scope.chartdata.Angular],
                        ['Bootstrap', scope.chartdata.Bootstrap],
                        ['Jquery', scope.chartdata.Jquery],
                        ['Communication', scope.chartdata.Communication]
                    ],
                    type: 'pie',
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    format: {
                        value: function(value, ratio, id, index) {
                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: Main issue is that pie chart is not loading, but am getting the pop up modal and when I re-size the window am getting the pie chart too. so am looking for the code that supports my directive (loading the pie chart with out need of window re-size)